# Inner join in SQL Server based on lookup table

Tags: sql-server, join

I have the following table structure:

```
create table table1( ID int,
                    assettype varchar(50));

create table t1( poolId int,
                 day_rate float);

create table t2( poolId int,
                 day_rate float);

create table lookuptable( tablename varchar(50),
                           assettype varchar(50));

insert into table1 values (1,'abs'), (2,'card');

insert into t1 values ( 1,5), ( 2,10);

insert into t2 values ( 1,15), ( 2,20);

insert into lookuptable values ('t1','abs'), ('t2','card');
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e4d9a/1/0)

For a given id based on the assetType field in table1 I need to perform a lookup in the lookup table so that I display if the assettype of the id is abs

```
poolId day_rate
1       5
2       10
```

else if the assettype of the id is card

```
poolId day_rate
1        15
2        20
```

The reason I have t1 and t2 tables because they have their own set of calculation and based on the asset type of the id i want to use t1 and t2

Would you be able to guide me with some query or steps to go in the right direction

I can think of the case when structure to this but in my case I have 100 entries in the lookuptable and that would mean a  case when structure written for 100 times. Is there a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
declare @table varchar(20)
select @table=tablename from lookuptable where assettype = 'card'
print @table

declare @query nvarchar(1000)
set @query = N'select * from [' + @table +']';
print @query

EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
```

Change the `assettype` in first query..

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to get all the rows in table1 and then their day_rates depending on what type of asset they are? Couldn't you do something like this.

```
select
,table1.ID
,table1.assettype, 
,(case when table1.assettype = 'abs' then t1.day_rate else t2.day_rate end) as
day_rate
from table1

inner join t1 on table1.id = t1.poolId
inner join t2 on table1.id = t2.poolId

group by table1.ID, table1.assettype
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me identify the perspective first.

First, you created this table1 as? well whatever, but this seems a lookup table as well to me.

```
create table table1(
   ID int,
   assettype varchar(50)
);
```

Next, this one is a lookup table as well because this one is your reference for calculation.

```
create table t1(
  poolId int,
  day_rate float
);

create table t2(
  poolId int,
  day_rate float
);
```

Lastly, is your direct lookup table depending on the assettype defines which table you will get the rate.

```
create table lookuptable(
    tablename varchar(50),
    assettype varchar(50)
);
```

So, i'll try to simplify this.

One is your table1 with an additional column

```
create table table1(
   ID int,
   assettype varchar(50),
   day_rate float
);

    insert into table1 values 
 (1,'abs',5)
,(2,'card',10)
```

I have no further reasons **yet** to split the table as One-To-Many table relationship as I don't see the lookuptable as "child" as well as t1 and t2. You could instead directly change the rates in table1 rate as desired.

Please put some comments so we can arrive at the same page. thanks